# Where do custom git merge drivers get stored?

Tags: git, git-merge, gitattributes

I was reading [this blog post](http://blog.joshhaas.com/2014/06/how-to-merge-json-files-using-git/), since I needed a custom git driver to merge a few json files in my git repo.

The instructions on the [script](https://gist.github.com/jphaas/ad7823b3469aac112a52) mention editing `.git/config` to add the merge and also editing the git attributes in `.gitattributes` but do not mention where to place the actual custom driver.   Does it just have to be on the `$PATH`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be stored anywhere on your file system. The `merge.<merge driver>` configuration option includes a `driver` key, which will be executed when the merge driver is invoked. This `driver` command can be anything you could run on the shell, so it can be the full path to a program or just the name of a program on your `$PATH`.